# Time format in python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a date that looks like this :

```
November 19th 2015, 12:48:34.402
```

And I need to figure out a way to convert it to a timestamp. I'm trying it this way but I can't find the right pattern to format it.

```
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(parsed["_timestamp"], "%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
```

Any suggestion on maybe how to get the right format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formatting string was a bit off. You need to include the `th`, `rd`, etc., the decimal point for the seconds, and the microseconds (which is `%f`). We'll find the proper `th`/etc. with a `split()`:

```
>>> a = 'November 19th 2015, 12:48:34.402'
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%B %d{} %Y, %H:%M:%S.%f".format(a.split()[1][-2:])).timetuple())
1447966114.0
>>> a = 'November 23rd 2015, 12:48:34.402'
>>> time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%B %d{} %Y, %H:%M:%S.%f".format(a.split()[1][-2:])).timetuple())
1448311714.0
```

Comment: 1st, 2nd ect would not work that way and that was my prob, you know something about that?

Thanks for the %f, couldn't find it! :)

Comment: @JonathanG - That's an excellent point; sorry I didn't even think of it. The edit takes care of it.

Comment: You da real MVP :) Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
import datetime
import time
timestring = "November 19th 2015, 12:48:34.402"
timeformat = "%B %dth %Y, %H:%M:%S.%f"
print int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, timeformat)))
1447962514
```

If you're ok with using `dateutil` then you don't have to worry about the format much:

```
import dateutil.parser

timestamp = int(time.mktime(dateutil.parser.parse(timestring).timetuple()))
print timestamp
1447962514
```

Comment: What happens with `1st, 2nd and 3rd`?